# Regex Password Validation using Or

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

I need to validate a password with these rules:

Password must have 6-12 characters
and at least two of the following:
Uppercase letters, Lowercase letters, Numbers or Symbols.
Below is my current regex:

```
^((?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*[A-Z])|(?=.*\\d)|(?=.*(_|[-+_!@#$%^&*.,?]))).{6,12}
```

I am struggling about how to make the 'at least' condition.

Comment: It's going to be exceedingly hard to do this with just a regex. You *might* be able to do it by stacking multiple non-consuming preconditional expressions after each other.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Not hard, just it will look very awkward. However, *6-12 characters **or more*** is unlcear.

Comment: I would split these requirements for a couple for isolated regexps. You would test each condition in isolation and prompt an error if more than two wouldn't be satisfied.

Comment: OK, it seems actually you can stack non-consuming groups after each other. Since I don't have enough experience with this I won't post this as an answer but the structure of your regex pattern would be like this: `@"(?<=P1)(?<=P2)(?<=P3)$"` where P1, P2 and P3 are three things you need to check in your password. So for instance to check the presence of uppercase, lowercase, digits, and the length of 6-12 you could do this: `@"(?<=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z].*)(?<=.*[a-z].*[a-z].*)(?<=.*\d.*\d.*)(?<=.{6,12})$"`.

Comment: On second thought I'll post it as an answer and then just delete it if someone finds a hole in the logic.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I just updated the policy its 6-12

Comment: Just use 3 separate checks with 3 separate regexes `[a-z]`, `[A-Z]`, `\d`, `[-+_!@#$%^&*.,?]`, and increment some counter on match. Check the string length with regular string functions. Isn't that possible? Please clarify where you are using the regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks a lot, I am using it on iOS

Comment: Please see what I mean [here](https://ideone.com/UNN3Bn).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes I know actually I think this is the only solution I have for now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may define a function to check your requirements one by one and increment a counter to see how many of them actually are met. If more than 1 matched and the string length is between 6 and 12, the password passes.

```
NSUInteger checkPassword(NSString * haystack) {
    NSArray * arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"(?s).*\\d.*", @"(?s).*[a-z].*", @"(?s).*[A-Z].*", @"(?s).*[-+_!@#$%^&*.,?].*",nil];
    NSUInteger cnt = 0;
    for (NSUInteger index = 0; index < [arr count]; ++index) {
        NSPredicate * passTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", [arr objectAtIndex:index]];
        if ([passTest evaluateWithObject:haystack]) {
            cnt = cnt + 1;
        }
    }
    if (cnt > 1 && [haystack length] > 5 && [haystack length] < 13)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And a sample [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/F3FinR):

```
NSString * s = @"123DF4ffg";
NSLog(@"Result: %d", checkPassword(s));
// => Result: 1
```

**Note** that it is possible to write a single pattern for this, but it will be rather long and clumsy as you need to define all possible pairs of lookahead alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this

```
^(?:(?=.*[a-z])(?:(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\\d\\w])|(?=.*\\w)(?=.*\\d))|(?=.*\\w)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)).{6,12}$;
```